# AsyncStorage size limit with expo managed app during dev and before submitting

Tags: asyncstorage, expo-go

I have developed an Expo Managed React Native mobile app which helps creating checklists for users. I have went through with it using AsyncStorage to store the lists and the items created in them. I needed Asyncstorage to be able to locally store the data for users to not be needing to login in and also without the need for any cloud storage option.

I have explored switching to SQLite but did not want to bother yet getting familiar with querying of data and sync. Also got too excited about Realm and MMKV but the issue I'm having is that it does not work with expo go and will require me to eject from expo as well as create a development client to be able to test the app on the emulator or physical device.

I have read in the expo docs that we can increase the size limit of AsyncStorage by adding a an entry in the build.gradle file. As you might be aware, in the case of an expo managed workflow app, the android and ios folders do not exist and I believe they would only be there once the app is built using expo-build.

Am I correct in assuming that I could continue with the final steps of development as is and just before submitting the app to the stores I could add the entry to the build.gradle file after building the native directories?

I have also created many dummy lists with dummy items in them to try and anticipate how the asyncstorage size would look like and researched a lot trying to find out how to find the size using the Android Studio Emulator but did not succeed in my search.

I cannot stress enough again how excited I was using Realm or MMKV for the purpose of this or a similar app but the worry of breaking the app by moving to a bare workflow is worrying me.

Would really appreciate any advice or previous experience in this regard.

Thanks in advance!

Tried the Realm Expo template and all sorts of errors related to Java version, gradle dependencies, and dev client creation started coming up. Also tried MMKV until I knew that it definitely would not work with Expo Go which is a huge preference of mine for now.